# multiple taps of a uitableviewcell result in exception: Application tried to present modally an active controller

Tags: ios, swift

i'm not sure if there is a real "solution" for this, but when I press multiple times on a tableviewcell really quickly, i get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present
>   modally an active controller

If I press just once, my code works fine. It's only if I press really really quickly multiple times. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    selectedUserAtIndexPath = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section
    // download and show video
    playVideoAtCell((indexPath as NSIndexPath).section)

}

func playVideoAtCell(_ cellNumber: Int) {

    getDownloadURL(cellNumber) { (url) in

        self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
        self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer
        self.avPlayerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.videoItemFinished(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.avPlayer?.currentItem)

        self.present(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
            self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()
        }
    }
}


func getDownloadURL (_ cellNumber: Int, callback: @escaping (URL) -> ()) {
    let mediaID = mediaIntroQueueList[cellNumber]["mediaID"] as? String

    Constants.storageMediaRef.child("\(mediaID!)").downloadURL(completion: { (URL, error) in
        if let downloadURL = URL {
            callback (downloadURL)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code gives you all you need to know. You're trying to call this over and over when you tap the cell more than once:

```
    self.present(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()
    }
```

What you could do is check at the beginning of playVideoAtCell if you're player has already been created. Therefore you could assume it's already presented:

```
func playVideoAtCell(_ cellNumber: Int) {
    if self.avPlayer != nil { return }
```

Or you could add a bool in somewhere to keep track if you've already presented a modal view.

Comment: @makthrow no problem :) make sure to accept the answer if you were able to solve your problem!